# Excel Solver (evolutionary algorithm and GRG Method)

Tags: excel, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to minimize a non-linear function under certain constraints by using the excel solver.

As a starting point I'm using the GRG Method with some manually chosen values. One feature of this method is that the output depends on the starting values. Therefore I use different starting values to get the lowest value for my target function and this works fine (at least for the most part).

Now I want to test these results using an evolutionary algorithm (EA) which is also provided by excel. In order to perform an EA one has to set upper and lower limits for the values because the first population is drawn randomly from the value range. This also means that the values in the cells (which the solver is trying to calibrate in order to minimize my non-linear function) are unimportant.

But running the EA I get the feeling that the cell values are not unimportant for three reasons:
First: When my original values are close to the values already calibrated with the GRG method in most cases I get only a small modification of these values.
Second: When I start without any values (which should not matter) I get an error message that the solver could not found a better result (the time for this process is roughly the same as in the first case).
Third: When using start values that don't give the lowest value for my non-linear function (I know this because I used the GRG Method with different input values) the EA does not converge to a better solution. In most cases it does not respond at all.

In short I have two questions: Does anyone really know how the EA from Excel is working? (the basic algorith is from the company FrontlineSolvers but they have no information whatsoever about the exact mechanism).

Is there something wrong with my assessment on how this mechanism works?

Thank you.

Comment: From what I understand they actually use the current solution. I assume it will be part of the initial population.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is your statement based on my description or do you have real source for it? Because I thought that a general feature of an EA is that it is independent of the initial starting values and the initial population is generated by a random draft.